# How to scrape all data from this element? Nodejs/Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

**I want to scrape names, positions, and type (online/in person) from elements like these**

```
<div class="cse-userslist-user" data-user="178">
  <div class="cse-ul--img">
    <div class="cse-ul--img-child">
      <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/99574b52aaa5ecb0bea650602fecfbd7?s=100&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="Dina Abdelma">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cse-ul--content">
    <div class="cse-ul--name">Dina Abdelma</div>
    <div class="cse-ul--position">Head of SMEs, MDI</div>
    <div class="cse-ul--role">Online</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cse-ul-overlay">
    <div class="cse-ul-overlay-bg"></div>
    <a class="cse-open-popform cse-btn cse-btn--primary">
                                        Message                                    </a>
    <a href="#" class="cse-btn cse-btn--primary disabled">Schedule Meeting</a> </div>
</div>
```

I got to the login page, but I cannot scrape all of the data, I only got the first letter in one name.

Also, the number in data-user is always random, nothing else changes
I want to scrape data from those three elements and put them into an array/excel.

```
 <div class="cse-ul--name">Dina Abdelma</div>
 <div class="cse-ul--position">Head of SMEs, MDI</div>
 <div class="cse-ul--role">Online</div>
```

This is my current code to log in to the webpage (unrelated, it works)

```
  await page.waitForSelector('#username')
  await page.type('#username', login)
  await page.type('#password', password)
  await page.click('#ur-frontend-form > form > div > div > div > input')
  await page.waitForSelector('#cse-main > div > div > section.cse-section.cse-section--links > div > a:nth-child(2)')
  await page.click('#cse-main > div > div > section.cse-section.cse-section--links > div > a:nth-child(2)')
  await page.waitForSelector('#cse-main > div.cse-page.cse-page--networking.cse-global-bg > section.cse-section.cse-section--userslist > div > div.cse-userslist-button > a')
  await page.click('#cse-main > div.cse-page.cse-page--networking.cse-global-bg > section.cse-section.cse-section--userslist > div > div.cse-userslist-button > a')
```

**EDIT**

```
  var names = await page.$$eval('.cse-ul--name',
  elements=> elements.map(item=>item.textContent))
```

Works but doesn't scrape all of the data, just the data that's visible.

Comment: Can you share how you tried to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Beautiful soup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') # html = the given html page from your question

# looks for a div, class='cse-ul--name' and decodes the contents of it
print(soup.find('div', 'cse-ul--name').decode_contents())

# looks for a div, class='cse-ul--position' and decodes the contents of it
print(soup.find('div', 'cse-ul--position').decode_contents())

# looks for a div, class='cse-ul--role' and decodes the contents of it
print(soup.find('div', 'cse-ul--role').decode_contents())
```